# How to write a LaTeX package that bundles not only .sty and .cls files but also some logos in .pdf or .eps formats?

Tags: package-writing

I would like to make a LaTeX package with the following subdirs:

- `tex/latex/common` (a common `.tex` file shared among `beamer` and letter)
- `tex/latex/resources` (lots of pdf and eps files with graphical resources)
- `tex/latex/mybeamer` (a custom beamer theme with 5 `.sty` files)
- `tex/latex/myletter` (a `.cls` file for a letter template)

I would like to package these files into a single LaTeX package that users could install in an easy way. I read about the `.ins` and `.dtx` files and I can see how to pack the .sty and `.cls` files but what about the extra graphics - the resources folder which contains several PDF and `.eps` files?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I am using ctanify. Here you can see my makefile: https://github.com/marcodaniel/mdframed/blob/master/Makefile#L222

Comment: Depends exactly what you want to do. As `.eps` files are ASCII, you can include them in a `.dtx` (I do in `chemstyle`, for example).

Comment: If you look at the `beamer` core, you'll see it's subdivided within `tex/latex/beamer`, but that is because there are _lots_ of files. You don't necessarily need to do that for a smaller bundle.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### TDS structure

Assuming your LaTeX package is called `foobar`. Then according to TDS ([A Directory Structure for TeX files](http://mirrors.ctan.org/tds/tds.pdf)) the files would go below the following Directories:

- `TDS:tex/latex/foobar/` (for TeX files: .tex, .sty, images)
- `TDS:doc/latex/foobar/`  (for documentation files)
- `TDS:source/latex/foobar/` (for source files .dtx, .ins)

Further subdirectories are up to you. I would avoid them, if there are few files only. If there are many files, then further directory levels might help to organize the files.

Example:

- `TDS:doc/latex/foobar/foobar.pdf`
- `TDS:source/latex/foobar/foobar.dtx`
- `TDS:source/latex/foobar/foobar.ins`
- Other source files that are not provided in the `.dtx` file can be given in:
  `TDS:source/latex/foobar/` or
  `TDS:source/latex/foobar/resources/`
- `TDS:tex/latex/foobar/foobar.cls`
- `TDS:tex/latex/foobar/foobar-common.sty` (The TeX file for the letter class and beamer templates)
- `TDS:tex/latex/foobar/<foobar beamer file 1>`,
  `TDS:tex/latex/foobar/<foobar beamer file 2>`,
  ...,
  `TDS:tex/latex/foobar/<foobar beamer file 5>`
- `TDS:tex/latex/foobar/resources/<.eps/.pdf image files>`

If you additionally provide a `README` file, then I would use this name exactly (AFAIK CTAN convention) and put it in the `doc` or `source` subtree, depending on the contents of the file.

### Distribution form

For the distribution I would put these files including the directory structure in a `.zip` file `foobar.tds.zip` (without the `TDS:`/`temxf` root).
Then the installation is quite easy for the user, who can easily install by unzipping. Installation example for default home tree in Linux/TeX Live:

```
$ unzip foobar.tds.zip -d ~/texmf/
```

In case the package is installed in a system wide local `texmf` tree, the file name database needs to be updated (under root):

```
$ texhash
```

or

```
$ mktexlsr
```

### CTAN

A suggestion for the CTAN form, if you want to provide it there:

- `CTAN:macros/latex/foobar/foobar.dtx`
- `CTAN:macros/latex/foobar/foobar.ins`
- `CTAN:macros/latex/foobar/foobar.pdf` (documentation)
- (`CTAN:macros/latex/foobar/README`)
- `CTAN:macros/latex/foobar/resources.zip` (or unzipped in directory `resources/`)
- `CTAN:install/macros/latex/foobar.tds.zip`

Comment: Hi, I tried to zip a TDS folder with `zip foo.tds.zip foo`, where `foo` has the TDS sub directories, and got `foo.tds.zip`. But when I unzip this to the `TEXMF`-tree I get `TEXMF/foo/…`, i.e. the files aren’t out in the existing sub directories of `TEXMF/`. What’s wrong here?

Comment: @Tobi: `cd foo` and then `zip ../foo.tds.zip *`.

Comment: Thanks, I had to add `-r` to make it work. Now everything is installed as desired but with `\includegraphics{img}` I can’t access the file stored in `TEXMF/generic/images/foo/img.pdf` isn’t that part of LaTeXs search scope? (It’s what @MatthewLeingang suggested.)

Comment: Oops … it was my fault. I missed the `tex/` in the path :-)

Answer (score 10):

In the TeX Directory Structure (TDS) the directory names under `tex/latex` are a global shared resource so you need to not take too many and choose names that are unique to your package. So `tex/latex/resources` and `tex/latex/common` would not be good names (and I suspect wouldn't be accepted if you were to try to get the package included into a distribution such as texlive).

`beamer` and `letter` both share the same input path for tex files so there is no need to separate your beamer and letter files.

Comment: Yes. I agree - I will fix the folder names and make them quite unique to avoid any clashes with other packages.

Answer (score 8):

Here is the [TeX Directory Structure](http://tug.org/tds/tds.pdf) way.  Pick a name for your bundle.

- Put TeX files that could be used in any format in `tex/generic/bundlename`
- Put LaTeX files like classes and packages in `tex/latex/bundlename`
- Put graphics resources in `tex/generic/images/bundlename`
- Put documentation in `doc/latex/bundlename`
- Put docstrip sources in `source/latex/bundlename`

You'll see a lot of these in use if you look inside, for instance, the `pgf` distribution.  Then the install process is just to `cp -R` the directories into a `texmf` tree.