# How to provide a picture for a 'global' class?

Tags: graphics, document-classes, paths

Is there a way to provide pictures for a 'global accessible' class file?

To use my own class and style files from everywhere, I put them in

> C:\Users\myself\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\myfiles

One class file contains a titlepage

```
\ProvidesClass{classMyClass}[2014/05/06 my own class]
\LoadClassWithOptions{scrreprt}

\newcommand{\myTitelblatt}{
    \begin{titlepage}
        \includegraphics[width=8cm]{./pics/header}
    \end{titlepage}
```

Now I access the from let's say

> C:\myTexts\myText.tex

```
\documentclass{classFestoDocu_fbwk}
\begin{document}
\myTitelblatt
hello
\end{document}
```

Is there a way I can provide the picture 'header' for the titlepage in the class file the same way as the class file itself? I want no subdirection 'pics' in `C:\myTexts\`but in `C:\Users\myself\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\myfiles`.

Comment: You can put it in the same directory where your class is. This applies for pictures the very same way: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137/11002 Also see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108295/11002

Comment: @yo' yes I know, it'll work if i put the image in `C:\Users\myself\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\myfiles`(with no subdir) and change the code to `\includegraphics[width=8cm]{header}`. But is there a way I can put it in a subdir?

Comment: Just try it, it should IMHO work. But, why would you want it?

Comment: Did you try `pics/header` instead of `./pics/header`?

Comment: I put the picture in a subdir named `pics` in `...\tex\latex\myfiles\` and still the command is just `\includegraphics{header}` (picture is named 'header.png'). Seems LaTeX finds the picture if the path is known and the file name unique.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was already there:

Put the image in a subdir of your choice under

> C:\Users\myself\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\myfiles

The directory has to be a known path and satisfy the TeX directory structure.
Also give your image an unique name.

Following open your command cosole (`cmd`) and type (and execute):

```
texhash
```

The code in your class file is just

```
\ProvidesClass{classMyClass}[2014/05/06 my own class]
\LoadClassWithOptions{scrreprt}

\newcommand{\myTitelblatt}{
    \begin{titlepage}
        \includegraphics[width=8cm]{header}
    \end{titlepage}
```

Note: there is no subdir given for the `\includegraphics`, but it seems LaTeX finds the image due to it's known path and unique name.